# Javascript Fullscreen API: Differences in fullscreen size calculation between browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, fullscreen

I have implemented some functionality to enable a user to expand a container div to fullsize. That div contains a chart that can become bigger, and with "overflow: auto;" it is made scrollable. Due to the payout of the site's pages the div only uses a small portion of the page, and the fullscreen mode offers the user the ability to see more of the chart contained in the div at once.

Using the API as explained in http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen works fine, I just had to add more vendor names for internet explorer.

What I find interesting is that different browsers use different sizes and/or positions for the maximized state. I recognized this because I have an absolutely positioned child element inside my container element, which is positioned at the top right.

When I change the container div to fullscreen mode in Chrome, the child element is visible at the top right of the screen. If I do the same in Firefox 29.0.1, that child element is hardly visible, the container div's top edge seems to be positioned about 10 pixel above the top edge of the screen and with it the child element.

Admittedly I changed devPixelsPerPx in Firefox's config. But setting it back to -1 doesn't change anything. Has somebody heard about any other factors that could influence the way Firefox computes an element's size when switching it to fullscreen mode?